# Firebase not responding in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I am trying to insert user data into the real-time database(Firebase). But when I run the app on an emulator or on my phone it just keeps loading(I set up a loadingBar to dismiss when a response is received) I tried going through the logcat to find an error message I got this

> Fetching config failed. code, error: 0, java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "app-measurement.com": No address associated with hostname: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeq.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement@@20.0.0:26)

I checked the rules, the dependencies looked through the web I can't seem to find what I missed.

I thought I should mention the first time I tried using firebase I faced the same problem on a less serious project so I didn't sort it out. That time I was using FIrebaseAuth so I decided to use a different approach this time.
here is the signIn code.

```
private void allowAccessAccount(String phoneNumber, String password) {
    final DatabaseReference rootRef;
    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.child(PARENT_DB_NAME).child(phoneNumber).exists()) {

                User userData = dataSnapshot.child(PARENT_DB_NAME).child(phoneNumber)
                        .getValue(User.class);

                if (userData.getPhone().equals(phoneNumber)) {

                    if (userData.getPassword().equals(password)) {

                        if (PARENT_DB_NAME.equals("Admins")) {

                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                            //Open Home Activity
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, AdminPanel.class));
                            finish();


                        } else if (PARENT_DB_NAME.equals("Users")) {

                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                            //Get User Data
                            Prevalent.currentOnlineUsr = userData;

                            //Open Home Activity
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        }
                    } else {

                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                        inputPassword.setError("Incorrect password");

                    }
                }
            } else {

                inputPhoneNumber.setError("Not registered");
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Here is the signUp code

```
private void signUpUser(String username, String phoneNumber, String password) {
    final DatabaseReference rootRef;
    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(phoneNumber).exists())){

                HashMap<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();

                userDataMap.put("username", username);
                userDataMap.put("phone", phoneNumber);
                userDataMap.put("password", password);

                rootRef.child("Users").child(phoneNumber).updateChildren(userDataMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                    //Account creation successful
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();

                                    //Open Sign In Activity
                                    startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,SignInActivity.class));
                                }
                                else {
                                    //Account creation Failed
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                inputPhoneNumber.setError("Already registered");
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: did you add the json file?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal yes i did

Comment: You say "I am trying to insert user data into the real-time database(Firebase)" but I cannot see any code that writes data to Firebase. Can you share it?

Comment: @AlexMamo Both inserting and retrieving isn't working but let me copy it and i will add it to the original post

Comment: I still cannot see any code that writes data to the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo in the signUp code i am updating the children of a phone number(userId) that doesn't exist so that's creating that user and adding the information using a HashMap

Comment: Instead of describing what you are doing, add the corresponding code.

Comment: @AlexMamo its alright sir I managed to fix it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what went wrong as I ran through every little thing over 5 times looking for where I went wrong. I fixed it by removing firebase and letting the assistant add it for me. I also removed the Jcenter repository plus I changed the email I was using for android studio to correspond with the email I was using for the project.